# Find and print the sub-string with wildcard character in a file on windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm pretty sure this is a simple command but I just couldn't find it anywhere.

Example file content:

A-VERY-LONG-LINE-OF-GARBAGE-VERSION123-CONTINUE-LONG-LINE-OF-GARBAGE

1.)Assume the line is really really long

2.)I need to find out what version it is. I know it contains Version but I wouldn't know it is version123.

3.)What I want is a command that would go through the file looking for the sub-string "VERSION" and if it finds it prints out VERSION123 instead of the super duper long line that would most probably causes the system to freeze.

Thank you

Comment: so in your line after version there will be version number as integer and after that there will be alphabets or special character? will there be only 1 version or multiple number or version123

Comment: please show us a real sample of these lines

Comment: Please tell us whether you are *really* working in **MS-DOS**, or if you are using the command prompt in **Windows**, because the latter supports lots of additional features...

Comment: What do you mean with "really really long"? More than 1023 characters? More than 8192 characters?

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion. It is not MS-DOS. It is just the command prompt or batch script. Initially, it was supposed to be a binary file that contains "version" but doing a "FIND" command will return everything in the file instead of the sub-string itself

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that version is purely numeric and does not start with zero, the following should do it:

```
set VAR=A-VERY-LONG-LINE-OF-GARBAGE-VERSION123-CONTINUE-LONG-LINE-OF-GARBAGE
set /A VAR=%VAR:*VERSION=%
echo VERSION%VAR%
```

If there occur multiple `VERSION` portions, the first one is taken.

Note, that this works for Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`) only, it will *not* work for MS-DOS (`command.com`) due to `set /A` which is not supported there (I'm even not sure whether the string substitution syntax works there)!

---

In case the version code is not purely numeric, you might use the following:

```
set VAR=A-VERY-LONG-LINE-OF-GARBAGE-VERSION123-CONTINUE-LONG-LINE-OF-GARBAGE
set VAR=%VAR:*VERSION=%
for /F "tokens=1 delims=- eol=-" %%L in ("%VAR%") do (set VAR=%%L)
echo VERSION%VAR%
```

This relies on the fact that the `-` character delimits the version code.

If you want to try this in the command prompt directly rather than in a batch file, replace `%%L` by `%L` (twice).

Comment: won't work in MS-DOS. Just to mention, I'm pretty sure, OP is using `cmd`, not MS-DOS (despite his headerline). Nice combination of `/a` and string substitution. (assuming, the version is Numbers-Only)

Comment: Hi sorry, I meant windows command prompt. However, the version number is not purely numeric. It might contain alphabet or even "." . Anyway to go about that? Thanks

Comment: @steve, I added an alternative for non-numeric versions to my answer, assuming it is separated from the rest by `-` (according to your example string)...